# caffe recompile with -fPIC libglog.a error

Tags: makefile, debian, caffe, fpic, glog

I'm trying to install Caffe on Debian, but when i do `make all` i get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(logging.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> /usr/local/lib/libglog.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1

where should i add the `-fPIC` flag?
I also read that it wasn't enough for `gflags`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does Caffe have documentation on adding to any specific `CFLAGS`-like variable? You might also want to report to them that their build is broken (because it is) and that they should be handling this themselves.

Comment: i can't find  any documentation about adding specific `CFLAGS`

Comment: Oh, hm, I hadn't properly read that error. That might be an issue with how you compiled the `glog` library. (I assume you compiled that yourself.) You might need to recompile *that* library with `-fPIC`.

Comment: after some tries i solved recompiling `glog` and `gflags` with `-fPIC`
thank you :)

Comment: If you can write up your solution you should add it as an answer here and accept it. You might also want to report this to the `glog` people.

Comment: I have the same error but with libboost-python.a `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a(dict.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only solution in to recompile the problematic 3rd parties with -fPIC. (Unless you can link to the .so instead of the .a)
The standard build of static libraries in packages is to build without -fPIC.
In glog, for example, you should add it to the C flags in compile.ac.

Answer (score 0):

In glog, adding `-fPIC` to `AM_CXXFLAGS` in `Makefile.am` works. Adding it to the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable had no effect for me.